# Move group instances together after rotation

Tags: modeling, groups, instances

I am trying to model a tripod. The idea was to model just one leg, making it a group, and then create two group instances of the leg, rotate them +-120 degrees (to face each other) and voila.
The problem I have though is that once rotated the grouped instances no longer move in the same global direction as the original leg. Instead, after the rotation, if I move the leg along the x axis, the instances will move along THEIR x axis thereby breaking the tripod apart.

Without rotation: 
[image]
With rotation:
[image]
Is there a way to move these rotated instances in the same global coordinate as the original leg?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set Transform orientation to Global, not Local. It seems that 3d manipulator widget confuses you and you drag with it.

You can move them along global axis also via keyabord -  <kbd>G</kbd> >
 <kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Rightclick</kbd> Drag + <kbd>X</kbd>.